# Return high quality results in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

I'm sending search queries to my ES index and get multiple results back. A lot of times the results with lower scores are irrelevant and I want to remove these results and return only high-quality results (which mostly have a higher score).

My index contains 1000 documents of type text of 100-500 words. For example - `{"text":'AVENGERS: ENDGAME is set after Thanos' catastrophic use of the Infinity Stones randomly wiped out half of Earth's population in Avengers: Infinity War. Those left behind are desperate to do something -- anything -- to bring back their lost loved ones. But after an initial attempt -- with extra help from Captain Marvel -- creates more problems than solutions, the grieving, purposeless Avengers think all hope is lost.'}`

If the user searches for 'Captain Marvel aka Brie Larson kills Thanos in the movie', the above document should be returned as a result since it contains similar terms.

Currently, I am using min_score to set the threshold, but I know it's not best practice and the scores vary depending on the number of documents in the index (which will keep growing). So this approach doesn't seem scalable.

I also tried multiple ways of tuning the query to get high-quality results back, such as More Like This functionality

```
"must": 
[{"more_like_this" : {
"fields" : field_list,
"like" : query_data,
"min_term_freq" : 1,
"max_query_terms" : 50,
"min_doc_freq" : 1,
"minimum_should_match" : '50%'}}]}}
```

But I'm still getting results with low scores like 1.5, whereas a good quality result usually has a score of 20. Is there a good way to tune the query further or adjust the min_score to be dynamic to only return highly relevant documents? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should provide your data and mapping as an example, its hard to help when u dont know on what data you are searching.

Comment: @aHochstein - Updated the post to include information about the data. Essentially I'm just searching through text information. I haven't updated any other settings in elasticsearch.

Comment: @aHochstein Did Shreya Jain's updated information help?

Comment: You can take the maximum score of the first document and normalize the rest of the documents by dividing by this maximum. Then you can filter with a threshold, for example keeping those that have at least 50 % of the maximum score. That's something that the service calling ES would have to do, you cannot do it directly in the query.